# How to support text editing when the text has to be synchronized with fixed audio?

Tags: synchronization, text-editor

In my application, we record audio of people speaking, send this to a speech-to-text (STT) service, and present the text to the user for editing.

Simplifying a bit, the STT service returns results in the form of a long list of words with timings:

```
      "words": [
        {
          "value": "Today",
          "from": 0.34,
          "to": 0.75,
          "confidence": 0.865
        },
        {
          "value": "is",
          "from": 0.76,
          "to": 0.91,
          "confidence": 0.923
        },
        {
          "value": "Friday",
          "from": 0.92,
          "to": 1.36,
          "confidence": 0.783
        },

        ...
     ]
```

The `from` and `to` timings are offsets in seconds from the start of the recording, so in this example, the word "Today" starts at t=0.34s and ends at t=0.75s, and so on. (Confidence is a measure of the STT engine's confidence that it's right about the word, which I use elsewhere in the app.)

The timings are important, because I have a UI that knows where you are in the audio and indicates this with a mark in the text. You can play the audio out loud and the app moves the marker to keep the text location in sync, or, for any location in the text, when you hit play, it knows where to start playing.

So far so good.

The challenge I've got is how to handle it when the user edits text, because it would get out of sync with the timings. If you, say, delete the space between "Today" and "is", now you have one word, not two. What should it's "time" be?

I handle this particular case by just concatenating the times, but what should happen if you select from the middle of one word to the middle of another word in another paragraph and then paste a block of text? I can maintain a list of the words, but what should happen to the timings?

Is there a better way to organize my data structures to support text editing that can stay in sync with audio?

Comment: How do you mark the text when the audio is at 1.00 (in the middle of the word "Friday")? Can you use that same mechanism for marking larger blocks of text where you don't have any better timing information?

Comment: I guess the best strategy is not to allow arbitrary edits, but only edits which you can keep in sync with the timings, maybe with the option of letting the user adjust the timings.. For example, edits like "change one word", "concatenate two consecutive word", "split one word into two". The latter operation may split the timings into two halfs as default, but let the user adjust the timings afterwards.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: I can't, really. I only get timing information at the word level. If you put the caret in the middle of the word and enter a space, I split the word into two words, and have to interpolate a time when the first "word" ends and the second one begins.

Comment: @DocBrown: That's an interesting idea, but the goal is to leverage the familiarity that people have with just typing to edit. Constraining that would make a weird and unpleasant UX, I think.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: regular typing of single characters, or deletion of characters, can be mapped to the three operations I mentioned above, so a custom text editor could do this in the background. Copy/pasting would not work so easy. but is that really required for your use case? I guess the idea of the edits is to correct detection errors. This does not look to me as if copy/pasting of text is pretty important for that use case.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it is either far too broad, especially given the many unknowns: e.g, how do you compare length of text with timing (extreme example: there’s a word in 3 letters “yes” (pronounced yes), and I’d replace it with three other letters, “etc” (pronounced et-tzetera) ?

Comment: @Christophe: It's a difficult problem for a few reasons, one being the one you mention. The way I'm handling it so far is to treat word timings as canonical, and to distribute the time of that word uniformly across the number of letters. This is sometimes quite a poor assumption, but it's the best I've got so far.

Comment: How accurate does the final result need to be? I've seen other software do something very similar. But it has one huge advantage: it can predict durations of the synced elements very accurately from other information. For audio with steady speed it suffices to place 2-3 markers per minute; might be much more with text though, depending on the desired accuracy